# How to perform the big O analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Below is my code.

How can you perform the **big O** analysis for `intDiv(m-n, n)`, where `m` & `n` are two random inputs?

```cpp
intDiv(int m,  int n) {

   if(n>m)
       return 0;

   else
       return 1 + intDiv(m-n, n); 

}      //this code finds the number of times n goes into m
```

Comment: how many iterations will this run, for a given m and n? (assume they divide nicely)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the values of the `m` and `n`. In general, The number of steps involved for any pair of (m,n), such that n, m >=0 are **integer_ceil(m/n)**.

Therefore, the time complexity of the above algorithm : `O([m/n])`, where, `[]` represents the ceil of the number.

Answer (score 0):

I think it totally depends on `n` and `m`. For example if `n=1` then it it is `O(m)`. And when `n=m/2` then it is `O(log(m))`.